# Nested map function resulting in a TypeError after finishing execution

Tags: javascript

**code:**

```
window.reddit.comments("uq0mzi").sort('hot').fetch(function(res) {
 res[1].data.children.flatMap((item) => {
      console.log(item.data.body)
      item.data.replies.data.children.map(y => (y.data.body === undefined ? "" : console.log(" >>>"+y.data.body)))
 })})
```

**what I'm trying:** I'm using the reddit API wrapper to get comments and their replies of a post. first map prints out the top level comments, while the second map is supposed to print out the replies to those comments

**where its going wrong:** the code works, but after printing everything, I'm getting a type error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children')

how do I fix it?

Comment: It is saying that you cannot read `null` to get children property. This could be because either `res[1].data` is null or `item.data.replies.data` is null. Log both of them and check which one is causing a problem. Also, add it to this question.

Comment: Try adding error-catching blocks. As a rule, DON'T trust dynamic data (especially external), cause they might be null or undefined or not as expected.

Comment: @RonHillel where should I to add the error-catching blocks? I thought of adding in a if(...children !== undefined) { //run code } block, but I dont think it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite solution is to use getSafe function to avoid `undefined` errors.

If a nested value is undefined, a default value will be returned instead of `undefined`

```
const getSafe = (fn, defaultVal) => {
    try {
        if (fn() === undefined || fn() === null) {
            return defaultVal
        } else {
            return fn();
        }

    } catch (e) {
        return defaultVal;
    }
}

window.reddit.comments("uq0mzi").sort('hot').fetch(function(res) {
    res[1].data.children.flatMap((item) => {
         console.log(item.data.body)
         getSafe(()=>item.data.replies.data.children, []).map(y => (y.data.body === undefined ? "" : console.log(" >>>"+y.data.body)))
    })})
```

Comment: oh nice, it works! also sounds like a solid way to avoid these things, thanks for the advice!